# Reading Text From Row 1 Column 2 (ListView)

Tags: c#, listview, streamwriter

[image: Code]

I'm trying to write Column 1 + Column 2 for every row but I keep getting:

[image: Error]

I actually had it working at one point, but I re-opened the project and now it doesn't.
Any idea as to what's happening?

Comment: After you cleared the listview you don't insert anything. so how could you read anything let alone two things from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the discription of listitem.clear:Removes all items and columns from the control.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.clear(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Since the are no items in the listview you cannot retieve the first one(listview1.items[0])

Comment: Thank you, for some reason I didn't catch that.
You know how late night programming is :)

Answer (score 0):

You trying to access an array where the there is no data. You can surround it with a `try catch` also to avoid crash. or test there is data with an `if clause`

```
if(listview1.Items[0].subItems[1]!=null)
  sr.write(...);
```